# Absolutely force a function AFTER page load

Tags: jquery

I'm using a masonry plug in called wookmark, which is really great but I need it (resizing the image holding DIVs) to execute after everything has finished loading, so I do:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    handler.wookmark(); 
});
```

Which doesn't work, I know this because I see some images covered by elements the images were loaded into (external images therefore sizes can't be set) before the page was reset. Also, I've set the same function to activate upon the slighest scroll which then makes the  resizing work perfectly, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    handler.wookmark();
});
```

Question is, is there anything AFTER `$(window).load(function() {` which would make this work? `$(window).load(function() {` seemingly does not wait for external images

**UPDATE**

One thing I know I can do is:

```
$( "body" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    handler.wookmark();
});
```

So when users moves mouse it all corrects itself, which it does, but this is not ideal - I don't want to put a message on the page saying "jiggle your mouse for the best UX"

Comment: `$(window).load(` DOES wait for external images. what it doesn't wait for is images added to the dom later, such as images added by javascript at arbitrary times. There is no global handler for that, so you'll have to deal with that on a case-by-case basis with said javascript.

Comment: Is a functron a funky function?

Comment: @Charlie You don't know the functron dance? You are soooo last year ha ha updating title

Comment: @KevinB "$(window).load(" simply does not do what it says then? I know everything can be taken literally or not but literally, window load means what I see - the window - is finished loading - I think to be absolute though is impossible you could say (e.g. a jquery load after 15 seconds element) but images are pretty standard so jury out for me

Comment: My point was we (the people looking to help you) have no idea where the images you are waiting for are. they could be part of the DOM initially, or they could be added later. Only you know the answer to that. If they were part of the DOM initially, then window load would be enough.

Comment: @KevinB But I already said that didn't work in OP, in first paragraph (technically first line of second para actually), thats the whole point of the question. I'm not being pedantic, just stating facts as I see them. I appreciate any and all help, always.

Comment: My point exactly. the problem is, we can't help you if you don't know how the images are being included on the page. Your tests thus far indicate that they infact are not originally part of the dom. If that is the case, we can't help you without knowing how they are being added.

Answer (score 0):

I had successfully solved such a problem by using a ["selector listener"](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/13/better-javascript-library-for-the-dom/). I've used [the better-dom `extend` function](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dom/wiki/Live-extensions) to setup an initialization script for each image that will get added to the page. (But I don't know anything about masonry/woodmark.)

Something like this example:

```
DOM.extend( 'img', {
    constructor: function() {
        var currentImage = jQuery( this._node );
        currentImage.load( function() {
            currentImage.woodmark();
        } );
    }
} );
```